# Using jQuery to grab data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I haven't really looked into must `jQuery + JSON`. So heres my attempt.

I am wanting to pull data from: `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.14.2/data/en_US/rune.json` which is an array of data for League Of Legends Runes. I am looking to get the `name`,  `description`, `image -> w y x` and `stats` to be used in a project of mine.

I currently have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.14.2/data/en_US/rune.json", function(data){
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            console.log(value[5001]); //<--- this the ID for one of the runes, to test if it is working
        });
    });
});
```

This is the output:

[image: Rune ID: 5001]
As you can see, the `name`, `description`, `image -> w, x, y` and `stats` are shown, how would I get it to put these in the console (for chrome) for each one?

Hopefully you guys can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close to getting what you need. The problem is the $.each loop is looping over several JSON keys/values before getting what you want.

A JSON object is accessed through dot notation and you can navigate down each level as shown below.  Hope this helps.

```
$.getJSON("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.14.2/data/en_US/rune.json", function(response){
    console.log(response); // Has keys for type, version, data, basic
    // Data is an array of elements
    console.log(response.data[5001]);
    // Each entry has properties you access like this.
    console.log(response.data[5001].name);
    console.log(response.data[5001].description);
    console.log(response.data[5001].image.x);
    console.log(response.data[5001].stats);
});
```

EDIT

To iterate over the data array you would do $.each over response.data

```
$.each(response.data, function (index, entry) {
   console.log(entry.name);
   console.log(entry.description);
});
```

Comment: That's good to hear! Is it possible to get `name, desc, image, stats` for each item in the array, such as by using `response.data.name` etc?